# delete all subfolders using a batch file?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

To delete all `bin` folders rooting from any subfolders from the current path, I have the following script, this is what I've tried (as far as my knowledge about batch script is):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%i in ('dir /a:d /s /b *') 
do 
(
  set d=!i!\bin 
  if exist !d! rd !d!
)
endlocal
```

it doesn't work and looks like there is even some syntax error. But it's a pain to find out what it is. When I run the batch file from `cmd`, it says something like this:

```
/s was unexpected at this time.
```

Note that for that batch file to run from `cmd`, I have to change the `%%` to `%`, otherwise it complains

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

So it's ridiculous that if we want to run the batch file from `cmd`, we need to replace all `%%` with `%` first? really :D
If running the batch file directly (by double-clicking it), the console window closes immediately without giving me any chance to see what's wrong. I've even tried putting a `PAUSE` at the end so that it can pause but it does not work neither (I know there is some error before that making the pause not working as well).

Come back to my original problem, because I don't have a clue on what it's wrong here (with the message reported from the `cmd`) I'm really stuck at this. Hope you guys could find something wrong in my script and help me fix it.

Comment: Perhaps you're missing quotes, if folder names can contain blanks : use `"!d!"`.

Comment: @harrymc thanks for your suggestion, I will take a look back into this later when I have a good enough knowledge of batch scripting. The script in my question was written as the way I like (and understand), so it may be messy. Although I did hope that someone would help correct it that logical way (but they have given other approaches/styles instead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```all-bat
@echo off 

cd/d "%~dp0"

for /f delims^= %%i in (
  'dir /a:d/s/b ^| findstr /eil "\bin \obj"'
  )do echo; rd "%%~i"
```

---

---

- **Obs.: 1** Its syntax tends to serve other languages, but not bat/cmd script, this loop doesn't work in that way...

  ```all-bat
  for /f %%i in ('loop command') 
  do 
  (
     // dynamic variable %%i can be expanded, that 
     // doesn't mean it will be treated/expanded 
     // like a regular variable %i% at runtime !i!
  )
  ```

  > *The syntax of the command is incorrect.*

---

- **Obs.: 2** The code results in a listing on your screen, to run/delete your folder remove the `echo;` if the output looks correct

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`CD /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)

  - [`CD /d "%~dp0"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18310141/8177207)
- [`Dir /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)
- [`FindSTR /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [`Rd` |or| `RMDir /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/rd.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

  - [`For /F commands`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [`For /L /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html)
- [Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)

  - [`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)
- [Commands Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [Why do you need `"tokens"` and `"delims"` in `"for"`](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2319)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)

Comment: What if I want to delete the subfolders with more than 1 pattern, e.g: besides `/bin`, I need to delete the `/obj` as well... Your scripts works for deleting `/bin` thanks.

Comment: BTW, could you modify my script to make it work that way (I mean logically like that). I'm not so sure if your script may accidentally target all folders whose path ***contains*** the `\bin` in the middle instead of at the end (which is actually what I want).

Comment: delete folders that end with `\bin`, not those that contain `\folder\path\with\bin\not\end\with\bin\string`

Comment: please read my first comment as well, actually I have 2 patterns for the subfolders to be deleted, with the logic in my original script, any number of patterns can be fine but it's a pity that it does not work. For your script I don't know how to adjust it to make it work for more patterns. Thank you for your help.

Comment: ...`ˆ|findSTR /End  /Literal /insensitive "string1[space]string2[space]string3.."`

Comment: thanks for your update, I'm very new to batch scripting so I'll take a deeper look into this later (currently there are still some things I find hard to understand).

Answer (score 2):

Use PowerShell, as it is much more powerful than cmd.

You need to install [PowerShell 7](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), then you may also want to install [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal), if you don't know how to install and open them, there are tons of online tutorials explaining the process better than I can, so I won't repeapt them here.

Run `pwsh.exe` with admin rights:

<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> -> type `pwsh.exe` -> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Then, in the console, to get all items inside "Path\to\folder":

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "Path\to\folder" -Force -Recurse
```

Only list subdirectories:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "Path\to\folder" -Force -Recurse -Directory
```

Filter the output of the first command according to pattern:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "Path\to\folder" -Force -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -match 'bin|obj' }
```

Remove all items filtered by the previous link in the chain:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "Path\to\folder" -Force -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -match 'bin|obj' } | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -Confirm:$false
```

The above does what you want, path\to\folder is a placeholder, change it to the actual (absolute) path, for example, if the path is "D:\MyFolder", change it to "D:\MyFolder", 'bin|obj' is a regex, if you need other patterns, replace it with the pattern you need, to construct the pattern, simply join the options using vertical pipes. Enclose the paths and patterns in quotation marks.

Warning: The above automatically deletes everything specified correctly without confirmation prompt, if you are not prepared do not run it.

Now to shorten the whole thing:

```
gci "Path\to\folder" -Fo -R | % {$_.Name -match 'bin|obj' } | ri -R -Fo -Con:$false
```

Enclose the code in a function to increase reusability:

```
function remove-filtered ($path, $pattern) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Force -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -match $pattern } | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -Confirm:$false
}
```

Comment: PowerShell is indeed superior but there is nothing wrong with using cmd.exe.  I use both every day and in many cases, ***I CANT USE POWERSHELL*** (as in it doesn't exist or execution permissions aren't set).

Comment: Thanks for your another interesting approach with using PowerShell, I give this one upvote but cannot accept it as the answer though.

Comment: Curious why you chose the -match operator instead of -eq.  seems to me this will make your otherwise very helpful example delete things under folders named anything that contains bin or obj such as "\BinaryObjectFormater\Formater.cs" or \DataTransferObjects\Customer.cs", etc.  which people who run this without fully understanding it may not find very helpful at all.